# jQuery UI widget autocomplete issue with fixed div parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm tryng to use this https://github.com/aehlke/tag-it script, no problems, i can add,remove tags and autocomplete function work very good.
My source:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#addTags").tagit({
            fieldName: "task_tags",
            availableTags: ["c++", "java", "php", "javascript", "ruby", "python", "c"],
            allowSpaces: true
        });
        //$("#addTags").tagit();
    });
</script>

<div class="panel">
  <div class="form-group">
    <ul id="addTags">
      <li>Tag1</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The problem start when I add my CSS:

```
<style>
  .panel {
   position: fixed;
   top: 30px;
   left: 90px;
  }
</style>
```

The div does not receive the right information on the position and remains fixed at the top left.

Comment: You mean the left, top properties have no effect on the UI? Create a fiddle with your code.

Comment: Cool tags-script. I tried it here. The positioning works as expected http://jsbin.com/nafiku

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved, the problem is that in my css I set a fixed position to the body and this block the window positions jquery ui.